# Laravel : passing data to session and auth::attempt

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on authentication module, I have the following code, The `if` condition is to check the form fields which is not working and the condition comes false.

Then the `else` the message is not showing there either.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => Input::get("email"), 'password' => Input::get("password")], true)) {

  return redirect()->intended('dashboard');

} else {
  return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with('message', 'Incorrect email or password.')
        ->with('form', 'login')
        ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
}
```

On the login view i have this chunk of code for errors :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger {{{ (Session::has('message') && Session::get('form', 'login') == 'login') ? '' : 'display-hide' }}}">
    <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
    <span>
        {!! Session::has('message') ? Session::get('message') : 'Please correct your fields.' !!}
    </span>

</div>
```

I am using ubuntu and the permissions are :

```
drwxrwxrwx 10 programmer programmer   4096 May 24 23:56 app
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer   1646 Apr 27 18:01 artisan
drwxrwxrwx  3 programmer programmer   4096 Apr 27 18:01 bootstrap
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer   1351 May 25 00:20 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer 124821 May 25 00:20 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx  2 programmer programmer   4096 May 24 23:56 config
drwxrwxrwx  5 programmer programmer   4096 May 24 23:56 database
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer    503 Apr 27 18:01 gulpfile.js
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer    212 Apr 27 18:01 package.json
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer   1026 Apr 27 18:01 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxrwx  6 programmer programmer   4096 May 24 23:57 public
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer   1918 Apr 27 18:01 readme.md
drwxrwxrwx  5 programmer programmer   4096 Apr 27 18:01 resources
-rwxrwxrwx  1 programmer programmer    567 Apr 27 18:01 server.php
drwxrwxrwx  5 programmer programmer   4096 Apr 27 18:01 storage
drwxrwxrwx  2 programmer programmer   4096 Apr 27 18:01 tests
drwxrwxrwx 31 programmer programmer   4096 May 25 00:20 vendor
```

Routes List :

```
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                        | Name                            | Action                                                      | Middleware              |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                          |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\CommonController@index                 | web,web,auth            |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard                  | dashboard                       | App\Http\Controllers\CommonController@routeDashboard        | web,web,auth            |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                      |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\CommonController@showLogin             | web,web,guest           |
|        | POST     | login                      |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\CommonController@authenticate          | web,web,guest           |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                     | logout                          | App\Http\Controllers\CommonController@logout                | web,web,auth            |
|        | POST     | password/reset             |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@postReset      | web,web,guest,guest     |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token}     |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\CommonController@showReset             | web,web,guest           |
|        | POST     | reset                      |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@postEmail      | web,web,guest,guest     |
|        | GET|HEAD | users                      | admin::users::manage            | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@showManageUsers        | web,web,auth,role:admin |
|        | POST     | users/edit-basic/{id}      | admin::users::                  | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@editUserBasicSave      | web,web,auth,role:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD | users/edit-basic/{id}      | admin::users::edit_basic        | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@editUserBasic          | web,web,auth,role:admin |
|        | POST     | users/edit-historical/{id} | admin::users::                  | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@editUserHistoricalSave | web,web,auth,role:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD | users/edit-historical/{id} | admin::users::edit_historical   | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@editUserHistorical     | web,web,auth,role:admin |
|        | POST     | users/handle               | admin::users::handle            | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@handleUsers            | web,web,auth,role:admin |
|        | POST     | users/new                  | admin::users::                  | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@newUserSave            | web,web,auth,role:admin |
|        | GET|HEAD | users/new                  | admin::users::new               | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@newUser                | web,web,auth,role:admin |
|        | POST     | users/validate-email/{id?} | admin::users::validate_email    | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@validateEmail          | web,web,auth,role:admin |
|        | POST     | users/validate-username    | admin::users::validate_username | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@validateUsername       | web,web,auth,role:admin |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: so whats the question here?

Comment: Why its not working :( !

Comment: Specifically the sessions . Why the message is not showing on the view !

Comment: Can you try to put backslashed on the session?

Comment: @geckob Still not working with backslash.

Comment: Can you just use session('message')

Comment: its also not working :(

Comment: Can you run php artisan route:list and include the result? I tried to replicate this but I cant

Comment: @geckob i am adding the routes list to the question please have llok i am updating the question.

Comment: @geckob Question updated. Have a look please

Comment: My guess is you don't have web middleware which will start the session. But I was wrong.  Can you go to app/storage/logs/laravel.log? Is there any errors happen when you made this request?

Comment: @geckob I have cleared the `storage/logs/laravel.log`, Then tried to login and when i came back to the laravel.log file that was empty means there wasn't any message or error. ??????

Comment: Other errors are coming but specifically related to our problem , nothing is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will not work because auth::attempt converts password to hash using bcrypt, and looks for that hash in users table to match.

in short the password should be a hash stored in database table for auth::attempt to work.

that is why your if() condition failing.

below is from laravel 5.2 docs

laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users

> The attempt method accepts an array of key / value pairs as its first
>   argument. The values in the array will be used to find the user in
>   your database table. So, in the example above, the user will be
>   retrieved by the value of the email column. If the user is found, the
>   hashed password stored in the database will be compared with the
>   hashed password value passed to the method via the array. If the two
>   hashed passwords match an authenticated session will be started for
>   the user.
>
> The attempt method will return true if authentication was successful.
>   Otherwise, false will be returned.

Comment: Still not working... I am updating the question please have a look .

Comment: please try to print Input::get("email") and check if it has required value.

Comment: `"shafee@hotmail.com"` is the output which is right.

Comment: OK, do you have routes under auth middleware ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112853/discussion-between-shafee-and-rakesh-goyal).

Comment: Are you logged in ? or plz try auth::check() first maybe.

Comment: can you post your route and middleware  list here?

Comment: No i am not logged in !

Comment: Yeah one sec.

`Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function ()
 {
  Route::get('/login',  "CommonController@showLogin");
  Route::post('/login', "CommonController@authenticate");
 });`

Comment: For dashboard...

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function ()
{
Route::get('/dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'CommonController@routeDashboard']);`

Comment: are you able to login via given username and password you are using? maybe password is not matching

Comment: plz try creating a new user and try this with that.

Comment: and let me know if it goes in if() or else() condition